# Chrome Auto-Complete Nightmare

Tags: google-chrome, field

I have a bunch of fields around the our system that all of the sudden, chrome decided to do whatever it wishes with.  Auto-filling a User ID in this field here (auto-fill-predictions enabled for debugging).

I have tried AutoComplete=off, AutoComplete=false, AutoComplete=none, AutoComplete=nope, AutoComplete=new-password, AutoComplete=stoptryingtoruinmylife

**Code**:

```
<input name="ctl00$cpMain$tbLimit" type="text" id="ctl00_cpMain_tbLimit" data-required="true" autocomplete="new-password">
```

**Screenshot:**

This is just one example, but there are examples all over our system showcasing Chrome's most annoying "feature" yet.  If this was labeled "UserID" or "EmailAddress" I could see the browser auto-filing it.

[image: Literally nothing indicating what to auto-fill here]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring the internet, seeing the issue obvious and apparent on so many websites I created my own work around.

On the top of the page I created a tag for UserID that the browser would autofill and no one would ever see as well.

```
<input type="text" id="UserID" name="UserID" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: -30px; width: 0; height:0" autocomplete="off">
```

This will place it off of the screen and Chrome will also autofill it instead of random other textboxes.